# Powerline modem ST7580 single channel mode

Tags: integrated-circuit, filter, power-line-communication

I'm trying to implement a powerline module with the [ST7580](http://www.st.com/web/en/catalog/sense_power/FM1968/SC923/SS1647/PF247185) modem.
There is a passive and active filter design in the [application note](http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/resource/technical/document/application_note/DM00050178.pdf) laid out which I plan to modify according to my desired carrier frequency.

It describes a dual channel modulation, but i plan to only use one carrier frequency for my B-PSK modulation. Can I just adapt the filters to the same frequency?

Comment: Can you be clearer about the type of filter - which page?

Comment: Its page 21/63 Transmission active filter and page 23/63 Reception passive filter from the application note.

Comment: But its not about the actual implementation of the filter. More about if its possible to transmit over a single carrier.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but yes it is possible to use one carrier at a time.
This is explained in the [UM0932 User manual](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/user_manual/8d/ce/5e/34/e0/03/41/ef/CD00270292.pdf/files/CD00270292.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00270292.pdf) throughout the document.

You can set up your modulation frequency upper and lower, on page 36/34 of the document you set a bit to choose the upper or lower frequency. This is the MIB setup section of the document. Important to read through all of it as the default setting will not work for your altered schematic.

You can also select the frequency you wish to modulate at in the DataRequest CDM on page 25 and 26.